# File Upload using Django Rest Framework getting error "No file was submitted."

Tags: django, django-file-upload

While trying to upload the file using Postman with Content-Type - multipart/form-data in the headers. I am passing both the fields, but I get the following error:

> Error:{"upload_to": ["This field is required."],"file_object": ["No
>   file was submitted."]}

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework_nested import routers
from utils.views import TemporaryImageView
from . import  views

router = routers.SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^upload-temp-image/$', TemporaryImageView.as_view())
]
```

## views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
import django_filters.rest_framework
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser, MultiPartParser, FormParser
from utils.serializers.temporary_image import TemporaryImageSerializer

class TemporaryImageView(CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    serializer_class = TemporaryImageSerializer
```

## serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from utils.models.tempfile import TemporaryFile

class TemporaryImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = (('Company Logo','/company/logos/'),
               )
    upload_to = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
    file_object = serializers.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = TemporaryFile
        fields = ('upload_to', 'file_object')
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
class TemporaryFile(models.Model):
    """
    a temporary file to backend
    """

    file_object = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Please help...I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Did you remember to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your template where the form is submitted?

Comment: yes..i am providing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed my models.py file in the way below and it works as expected..

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

def get_image_path(instance, filename):

    if instance.upload_to == "company_logo":
        path = 'company/logo/'
    return path


class TemporaryFile(models.Model):
    """
    a temporary file to backend
    """

    file_object = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to=get_image_path)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.upload_to = kwargs.pop("upload_to")
        super(TemporaryFile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```